# How to detect the ammount of dedicated video RAM (on Dell)

Tags: memory, graphics-card, bios, dell-optiplex, vram

Is it possible to increase dedicated video RAM on Dell Optiplex 990? I have 1696 available graphics memory, but I can't seem to change anything related to the dedicated video RAM anywhere even in the BIOS. How do I change it?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official specification sheet](http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/optiplex-990-spec-sheet.pdf), unless there is an separate video card installed, this PC uses Intel HD 2000 graphics which is built into the processor. In HD 2000 graphics, there is no dedicated GPU memory but rather it uses shared system memory borrowing from normal RAM installed in the system up to the maximum allowed by the GPU (1696k in this case). There is no way to increase the GPU RAM and in many implementations you cannot control it in any way.

On a good note, all of these models except the USFF chassis has a PCI-Express 16x slot allowing you to install an aftermarket half-height  (sometimes called Low Profile) graphics card. There are multiple options available anywhere from $20 and up you could increase your graphics performance significantly, even a low end discrete card would increase your graphics capabilities tremendously.

Comment: @LordTinkleDicks Sorry if it isn't the answer you wanted, but it is the truth from a technical perspective, you can't change the allocated shared memory on the integrated GPU.